# Apache URL rewrite , URL with undefined number of parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls of the form

```
http://www.site.com/someCompany/someEmployee/name/someName/age/someAge/.../keyN/someValueN/
```

I am trying to convert them to the regular key=value form, but cant figure it out.

Can you please help me convert it to

```
http://www.site.com/someCompany/someEmployee?name=someName&age=someAge&...&keyN=someValueN/
```

Basically, there can be any number of keys and values and its specified in the URL as /key/value/

I read many examples and tutorials but none of them explain processing URLs with variable number of parameters.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite turned on.

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these (preferably above other rules that you may have there):

```
# Start converting query parameters to path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/(.+?)\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2/%1/%2?%3 [L]

# done converting, redirect browser
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/(.+?)\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]


# internally rewrite paths to query strings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*) /$1/$2$5?$3=$4 [L,QSA]

# only someCompany/someEmployee left, pass it through
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,R]
```

This is going to seem kind of complicated. But the first 2 rules checks if a given request is for 2 folders (e.g. `/something/somethingelse`) with a query string (everything after the `?`), then match name/value pairs out and construct them into the URI-path. When the query string is empty, redirect the browser to the new URL (without a query string). This makes it so when someone goes enters the URL into their browser:

```
http://www.site.com/someCompany/someEmployee?name=someName&age=someAge&keyN=someValueN
```

the browser gets redirected so the URL in the address bar looks like:

```
http://www.site.com/someCompany/someEmployee/name/someName/age/someAge/keyN/someValueN/
```

Then the second set of rules takes a path hierarchy, preserves whatever the first 2 folders are (e.g. `/fooCompany/barEmployee`) and changes each 2 folders into name/value pairs in the query string. Essentially reversing what the first 2 rules does, but it doesn't redirect the browser. It will only internally rewrite the URI.